# Segmentation Fault (Malloc/Free in a Loop)

Tags: c, malloc, free

I've been revisiting the C language and am having trouble freeing up memory after use in my program:

```
    int tvalue = 2;
    while (smult == 0) {
        int * tvaluearray = calloc(allnum, sizeof(int));    
        tvaluearray = frequencyArray(tvalue, allnum, tvaluearray);
        printf("tvalue = %d\n", tvalue);    
        //compare each index of the tvaluearray and the first array
        for (int j = 0; j < allnum; j++) {
//          printf("tvaluearray[%d]=%d >= firstarray[%d]=%d\n", j, tvaluearray[j], j, firstarray[j]);
            if (tvaluearray[j] < firstarray[j]) {
            //  printf("Found the false statement\n");
                break;
            }
            else if ( (j+1) == allnum ){
                smult = 1;
//              printf("Made it to else if! smult = %d\n", smult);
            }
        }
        free(tvaluearray);
        ++tvalue;
    }
```

The frequencyArray function is shown below:

```
int * frequencyArray (int target, int allnum, int targetarray[]) {
    int divisor = 2;

    for (int i = 0; i < allnum; i++)
        targetarray[i] = 0;
    //find the common factor frequency of the given number
    while (target > 1) {
        if (target % divisor == 0) {
            targetarray[divisor] += 1;
            target /= divisor;
        }
        else
            ++divisor;
    }


    return targetarray;
}
```

Having played around with this a bit, I've tried the following with different results:

1) removing the free of targetarray:

tvalue = 1306 --> segfault

2) including the free(targetarray):

tvalue = 29
free(): invalid next size (fast)
Aborted (core dumped)

3) including free(targetarray) AND allocating 4*sizeof(int) for the tvaluearray calloc as opposed to just int:

tvalue = 31468 --> segfault

The third test had me changing the allocated space for the array with varying results before my program runs into the segmentation fault error. This has me thinking that there's an issue with the way I'm allocating space, but I think it just might be a little bit beyond my current understanding. Do any of y'all see where I may be going wrong?

Comment: `tvaluearray = calloc(...)` directly followed by `tvaluearray = frequencyArray(...)`... Is that last assignment really needed? Do `frequencyArray` really need to return the `targetarray` argument?

Comment: Also in `frequencyArray`, what happens if the `while` loop runs a little to far, making `divisor` being out of bounds?

Comment: I think that it's a problematic design to assign the return from `frequencyArray()` to the pointer `tvaluearray`. That pointer is tracking your allocated memory! It should only be read from, not written to. Look at it this way: if the function `frequencyArray()` changes the value of the pointer, you're looking at undefined behavior (memory leak, crash, etc.). If it doesn't change the value, there's no point in returning anything.

Comment: Another minor point:. You've used the variable name `allnum` in `frequencyArray()` and in the calling code. The compiler will have no doubt which one is going to be referred to, but you might get confused. Specifically, note that if you change the value in the function, the value seen by the calling code won't change.

Comment: The divisor being out of bounds was the source of the error! Good to know about the array though. So is it a general rule of thumb to never pass pointers through a function?

Answer (score 0):

In `frequencyArray()` function you have a loop:

```
while (target > 1) {
    if (target % divisor == 0) {
        targetarray[divisor] += 1;
        target /= divisor;
    }
    else
        ++divisor;
}
```

where `divisor` is used as index of your `targetarray[]`. I can't see here any formal bounds for maximum value of `divisor` - it seems that it can grow over maximum allowed value (equal `allnum - 1`), so the memory outside `targetarray[]` can be overwritten resulting in memory corruption/segmentation fault. You should check in each iteration that `divisor < allnum` .

Unfortunately, I don't know the context of your code, so can't propose any appropiate solution here. Probably it should look like:

```
while (target > 1) {
    if (target % divisor == 0) {

        // 'fuse' ;)
        if (divisor >= allnum) {
           // place here the code needed to solve the problem or break to exit from loop
        }
        // end of 'fuse'

        targetarray[divisor] += 1;
        target /= divisor;
    }
    else
        ++divisor;
}
```

Comment: The divisor being out of bounds was exactly it! I added an else if statement to break once the divisor gets larger than allnum and the segmentation fault disappeared. It's amazing how sometimes the problem is at the heart of the algorithm as opposed to the syntax of the code.

As for the context, I'm working on a Project Euler problem and trying to respect the request to avoid posting solutions online so I'm purposely leaving it vague. Thanks for the troubleshooting!